# Can't start relay - certificate error

Tags: relays, private-key, certificate

Upon trying to start it I get this:

```
Mar 04 08:09:00 beeldbox Tor[30025]: No signature found on key certificate
```

Thing is this was working fine yesterday

I've finally built up enough consensus weight to be used as a relay and really don't want to start over..... Again.
I'm trying to transfer to a new server.

Both servers running Ubuntu 18.04.
Error reproducible on both

**EDIT** Removed all the cached certs and that's gone. Now it gets stuck @ Bootstrapping 0% with nothing further in logs.

```
Mar 04 18:02:54 * Tor[25711]: Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Mar 04 18:02:54 * Tor[25711]: Starting with guard context "default" 
Mar 04 18:02:54 * Tor[25711]: Signaled readiness to systemd
Mar 04 18:02:55 * Tor[25711]: Opening Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
Mar 04 18:02:55 * Tor[25711]: Opened Socks listener on /run/tor/socks 
Mar 04 18:02:55 * Tor[25711]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Mar 04 18:02:55 * Tor[25711]: Opened Control listener on /run/tor/control
```

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help with this, but what was the version of tor on the old server, and what's the version on the new server? Also double check that the permissions on all of the files are correct.

Comment: @Steve both servers 0.4.2.6

Comment: @Steve question updated

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be, is this with the default torrc? And you don't have any incoming/outgoing firewall rules that could be interfering? I would try deleting config files, re-installing tor, and using the default torrc (with default relay settings and a new cert). If that works, you can then start introducing changes and using your old relay's cert, and see when it breaks. If no one answers on here, I recommend asking on #tor or #tor-relays on IRC, you might have to wait a while, but it's a good place to ask for these types of technical problems.

Comment: @Steve I did try that same issue. So it not the keys

Comment: Is tor exiting, or is it still running but not logging anything after that? Can you increase your log level by setting "Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log" (using a correct path for your system) in your torrc? Is there more information? And if there's too much, use "info" instead of "debug".

Comment: @Steve logging found the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues were present:

1) Firewall was too restrictive preventing connections to a necessary port (53, for local dns resolving)

2) Torrc misconfiguration. Not entirely sure which option.

3) Network interface misconfiguration, preventing connections to the IP for was set to use (server had 2 ipv4 ips and /64 block of ipv6

4) Bad cached certs

Hope my struggle helps someone else!